# In matplotlib 3d-plotting what is the significance of the parameters rcount, ccount, rstride and cstride in plot_wireframe?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

In matplotlib 3d-plotting the function `plot_wireframe` takes parameters - `rcount`, `ccount`, `rstride` and `cstride` respectively. I went through the documentation for them in the matplotlib [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html#wireframe-plots) but it was not very clear what they did. I played around changing the parameter values of `rcount` and `ccount` a bit and have a sense that it has to do with how many rows and columns from the meshgrids X and Y are used for placing the wires (X and Y are the meshgrids input to `plot_wireframe`). I guess a clear understanding of rstride and cstride will follow after understanding rcount and ccount. Hence I request a better explanation of this with an example maybe.

Here is my code for reference (ran in Jupyter notebook)-

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    # Because I would want to rotate the plots manually
    %matplotlib notebook

    x = np.linspace(-3,3,7)
    y = np.linspace(-3,3,7)
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    Z = X**2 + Y**2
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
    ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z,rcount=3, ccount=5)
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways of saying the same thing.  Let's say you have 1000x1000 points.  If you specify `rcount=10` and `ccount=50`, it will downsample the data so it plots 10 rows and 50 columns.  If instead you say `rstride=10` and `cstride=50`, that will take every 10th point in the rows, and every 50th point in the columns.

So, for 1000x1000, `rcount=10` is the same as `rstride=100`.  They are mutually exclusive, and clearly, you don't really need both.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess rows and columns here denote the rows and columns of the 2D-arrays X, Y and Z to be used for plotting. Am I correct?

Comment: Yep, that's it.